# Shall car accident witnesses try to turn a capsized car back wheels down?

Tags: car, accident

In car accident videos on Youtube, I often see that when car gets upside down, other drivers and spectators typically team up to turn the car back to normal position.

Is it recommended course of action, assuming the car and driver is not obviously in bad peril (fire, broken neck)? Is it safe, legal, beneficial?

Factors to consider:

- Deliberately moving a vehicle that was in accident is typically illegal, unless required for rescue.
- It is easier to leave a car that is wheels down, not up.
- In case of serious injury turning the car may exacerbate it.
- The car may be damaged further by turning it. Or by leaving it upside down...
- Turning may be dangerous for the turners.

Comment: Fuel cannot leak out of breathers of a car sitting on it's wheels.  There is no law that I'm aware of that prevents moving a vehicle that's been in an accident although this may vary by jurisdiction.  If another vehicle subsequently crashes at the same point and collides with an upright vehicle, it's bumpers line up.  If it hits an inverted vehicle, the bumpers line up with the occupants heads.

Comment: Tell you what: if the car's upside down, chances are it's already damaged so much that it's an insurance write-off, so any further damage is unimportant.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair.

Comment: An upside down car is *eventually* going to have to be turned over, if for no other reason than to tow it away. Unless you plan on bringing out two cranes and some big fluffy straps and a physicist, rolling it over is as good a method as any.

Answer (score 1):

Thete are two basic cases here: rally cars and just ordinary motorists.

For rally cars, the occupants have much more extensive protection (helmets, neck support, 5 or mor point harness) and can be ok to continue. They are often found asking to be righted so they can continue as they are against the clock. This happens quite often when you see the damage sustained by some contestants who complete the stage .

Ordinary cars don’t have the same level of protection and either the occupants make their own way out or have to be removed due to other risks such as fire that are a higher priority.

Some occupants are trapped in either case and may need specialist help from perhaps the fire brigade ( hydraulic cutters etc) and medical teams.

My sister was hit by another car (ordinary road accident - not rally) and ended up in a field after rolling - the people at the scene looked at the car and thought since it was so badly damaged that they would not check. She was found, still alive, by the police nearly an hour later as the med team had looked after the other car first. I cannot print my opinion of those people except for “lazy ignorant b********” as she had to spend several days in hospital, exacerbated in the doctor’s opinion, due to the extended time without care...

Comment: Agreed - most of the videos you see on youtube will be rally cars in competition (which is why the cameras are there in the first place...)

Comment: I mean non-rally case. For example, a car swerves away from collision and drives down from roadside, capsizing in process. No damage except of capsizing itself, but people are not protected as in rally case.

Answer (score 1):

One assumes it differs based on the laws of each country. But I will assume that most countries would put a higher importance on saving someone's life than preserving the integrity of an accident scene for the purposes of police reports and insurance claims.

Besides, if there were eye witnesses, they could describe the scene as it was before and why the cars were moved/turned right-side up.

Answer (score 0):

ANY rollover auto wreck is considered by first responders as an indicator of *significant mechanism of injury* to the occupants; meaning a presumption of spinal injury.
Prior to moving a patient with suspected spinal injury, precautions must be taken to prevent aggravation (or causation) of related trauma.

You should **never** move the car or the occupants of a car after a rollover wreck unless you need to move them to avoid a life threatening situation e.g. fire, freight train approaching, car about to plunge off a bridge, etc. Let medical professionals stabilize and secure them and then move them while protecting their spine.

If they move/remove themselves, you should still presume spinal injury and ask them to lay down quietly and give them first aid (or moral support) until help comes; adrenaline can mask pain and shock.

Professional racers would be outside the scope of this discussion.

Comment: Surely the term "spectators" suggests motorsport and in particular, stage rallying.  I would hope that accident black spots don't attract spectators.

Comment: The OP states in an additional comment that he/she means non-rally situation and is perhaps using the term "spectators" mistakenly.

Comment: I meant "witness" instead of "spectator".